# How to make Github pages work for my site?

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to upload my site to Github Pages, have created a repository and activated Pages. But it is as if it does not see the css files and images, it only shows me the pages and the html. this is the link for my repository: **https://github.com/Giulie77a/flowerbee.git**

this is my link to GitHub Pages
**https://giulie77a.github.io/flowerbee/**
... the css and the image are not seen...

Would anyone know how to help me? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your paths for CSS and images in every files
Image path should start with `immagini/...`

and CSS path should start with `css/...`

### For image -

Change this

```
<img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang1.jpg" alt="Our Company" width="500" height="500">
```

to this -

```
<img src="immagini/Big Bang/BigBang1.jpg" alt="Our Company" width="500" height="500">
```

### For CSS

Change this -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/css/AboutUs.css">
```

to this -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/AboutUs.css">
```